# jQuery: Date Range Picker: prepend date in element

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

So i have this picker:

http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/date_range_picker_using_jquery_ui_16_and_jquery_ui_css_framework/

Now, how can I prepend the date/daterange you choose into div element #viewCalender, when you chose a date? 
I tried do:

```
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(function(){
                  $('#rangeA').daterangepicker({
                  arrows:true,
                  onChange: function(){
$('#calenderView').prepend('test');
}
                  }); 
             });
        </script>
```

But It prepends "test" twice into #calenderView, even tried with just alerts, and i get two alerts, after i picked a date, which I do not understand why??? And how can i prepend the date/daterange into it?

Comment: Can you show the html you're working with? I'm trying to reproduce your problem, but so far I haven't been able to. This is my attempt so far: [at JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3drW4/).

Comment: @David Thomas, the attempt is correct. Can you see it runs twice(double prepending) when you choose a date? "testtest" instead of only one "test", thats my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting a complete html document that one could copy and try immediatly would help a lot.

I can only guess, but I'd say:

```
$(function() {
    $('#rangeA').daterangepicker({
        arrows: true,
        onChange: function(event) {
            // try this one
            event.stopPropagation()
            $('#calenderView').prepend('test');
            // and/or this
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

---

#### Edit

I read the manual, and there it is stated that onChange is a callback that „executes whenever the date input changes (can happen twice on range selections).“

http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/date_range_picker_using_jquery_ui_16_and_jquery_ui_css_framework/

I set a breakpoint and debugged that script using Firebug. And whoopee, onSelect (line 69) fired twice, and because of that options.onChange (line 90) is fired twice.

Maybe you shout use onClose instead of onChange:

```
$(function() {
    $('#rangeA').daterangepicker({
        arrows: true,
        onClose: function(event) {
            $('#calenderView').prepend('test');
        }
    });
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/3zM3W/10/

Comment: Doesn't made any difference to the double-executing issue. Tried both solutions, it works the same way with or without return false; and with event.stopPropagation() it doesnt prepending anything at all

Comment: Please see and check: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3drW4/ , there's my issue and you can try your solutions and see that they won't affect it.

Comment: thanks for your answer, that worked nicely although it still runs if you open and close without selecting anything (no change), but maybe i could just check if theres anything in val, else dont prepend later.. How can I also prepend the date/range you choose